# My chatbot is not giving output when actions.py gets called

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am trying to make actionable chatbot on **Rasa** platform. my basic bot is working but whenever I am asking a question to my chatbot regarding database it is not giving me the output. and no error/exception is shown on the terminal.

Example
Me - What is pf uan number?

Bot -"empty"

//Below I have attached the code//

**domain.yml**

```
intents:

agent.acquaintance
agent.age

templates:

utter_agent.acquaintance:
- "I'm a virtual agent"
- "Think of me as a virtual agent."
- "Well, I'm not a person, I'm a virtual agent."
- "I'm a virtual being, not a real person."
- "I'm a conversational app."

utter_agent.age:
- "I prefer not to answer with a number. I know I'm young."
- "I was created recently, but don't know my exact age."
- "Age is just a number. You're only as old as you feel."

actions:
utter_agent.acquaintance
utter_agent.age
action_db
```

**Stories.md**

```
## story 01
*agent.acquaintance
utter_agent.acquaintance

story 02
*agent.age
utter_agent.age

Story 87
*pf.uan.number
action_db
```

**pf.uan.number.md**

```
## intent:pf.uan.number

Give my uan number
Lets go
my pf uan number
Your pf uan number
What is pf uan number?
```

**action.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from rasa_core_sdk import Action

import pymysql

class ActionDb(Action):
      def name(self):
return 'action_db'
def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
print("Hello1111")
db = pymysql.connect("xyz.net","admin","abcdefg","dbname")
cursor = db.cursor()
str1='PF_UAN_Number'
query = "SELECT COL_2 FROM csv_db1.TABLE_2 WHERE COL_1 = '" + str1 + "'"
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchone()
print(data)
dispatcher.utter_message(data[0])
return []
```

Answer (score 1):

the format of your stories.md file is wrong, every new story should start with `##` symbol and actions should be prefixed with `-`

Answer (score 0):

The formats of your *stories.md* and *domain.yml* file are wrong.

You have to comment out the lines `story 02` and `Story 87`with `##` and add `-` before utter.

So it will be like this:

```
## story 02 
* agent.age 
- utter_agent.age
```

In *domain.yml*, actions and intents should be prefixed with `-`.

So it will be like this:

```
intents: 
- agent.acquaintance 
- agent.age 
actions: 
- utter_agent.acquaintance 
- utter_agent.age 
- action_db
```

I would recommend you to check this documentation to see the correct format of [stories.md](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/stories/#format) and [domain.yml](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/domains/#an-example-of-a-domain) files: